# Go HTTP library thowing error when it's just imported, same for discordgo

Tags: go

whenever I import "net/http" or discordgo to my project I get this error

c:\go\src\vendor\golang.org\x\text\secure\bidirule\bidirule.go:16:2: read c:\go\
src\vendor\golang.org\x\text\unicode\bidi\tables11.0.0.go: unexpected NUL in input

My code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "regexp"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "bytes"
    "strings"
    "encoding/json"
    "time"
    "github.com/gookit/color"
    "github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo"
    "github.com/denisbrodbeck/machineid"


)



func main() {
  fmt.Println("test")

}
```

Comment: How did you install go? This seems like a bad install.

Comment: Using Go windows installer @Adrian

Comment: What version of Go? And what is the output of `go env`?

Comment: Here's output of go env https://hastebin.com/cavuhiqaki.sql and my go version is  go1.14.2 windows/amd64